# Diferença entre glFlush e glFinish

Tags: opengl

Qual é a diferença prática entre os comandos glFlush e glFinish no contexto do OpenGL ES 2.0?

Já li a documentação das duas funções [glFlush](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man31/html/glFlush.xhtml) e [glFinish](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man31/html/glFinish.xhtml), e ainda não consegui determinar *quando* devo utilizar uma em vez da outra.

Sei que um código simples funciona corretamente sem utilizar quaisquer dessas funções, e é exatamente por isso que gostaria de exemplos de código onde cada uma dessas funções se mostra indispensável.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os comandos OpenGL não são executadas imediatamente. Em vez disso, eles são submetidos a um *buffer* de comando que é então alimentado ao hardware. Os comandos `glFlush()` e `glFinish()` são ambos usados para forçar a submissão do *buffer* de comando para o *hardware* para execução.

## glFlush

Serve para enviar para o hardware todos os comandos emitidos até ao momento, permitindo assim que os *drivers* GL iniciem o *render* sem grandes demoras, também garantindo que num período finito todas as tarefas estarão concluídas.

Este comando faz `return` imediatamente após conclusão do envio dos comandos, não espera pelo *render* nem bloqueia a aplicação.

> **Exemplo**
> Imagina que estás a desenhar uma animação com bolas, aparecendo uma e depois outra e depois outra, etc..., chamando `glFlush` após cada `object` (bola), garantes que o [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) tem todos os comandos referentes à bola #1 antes de receber seja o que for referente à bola #2.

**Nota:** Não existem garantias de que o [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) tenha terminado a bola #1 ou sequer iniciado o *render* da mesma quando o `glFlush()` é chamado. Apenas temos a garantia que o [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) tem tudo o que precisa para o *render* da mesma.

## glFinish

É igual ao `glFlush()`, mas vai fazer com que a execução do programa espere até que esteja tudo desenhado até ao último pixel, até que o [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) não tenha mais nada para fazer.

Este comando só vai fazer `return` quando todos os comandos enviados antes dele estiverem concluídos.

> **Exemplo**
> De alguma forma útil quando existe interação com o sistema operativo e/ou utilizador e essa interação depende do *render* que está a ser feito.
> Outro exemplo é o caso de recursos partilhados entre `threads` onde uma está a carregar uma textura cuja mesma vai ser renderizada numa outra `thread`, onde o uso do `glFinish` vai garantir que a textura esta totalmente carregada antes do `render` iniciar na segunda `thread`.

**Nota:** Convém também saber que ao chamarmos `glFinish`, estamos de certa forma a perder o paralelismo que o [GPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) e [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) podem alcançar, uma vez que como `glFinish` tem por característica forçar a espera até que esteja tudo renderizado, na `thread` em que o mesmo é chamado, o GPU está a trabalhar em pleno mas o [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) está parado à espera do *render* enquanto podia estar a adiantar outros trabalhos. Com isto pretendo alertar para o uso cuidado de `glFinish`.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Por enquanto estou utilizando `glFinish()`, mas posso estar perdendo desempenho. Vou testar com `glFlush()` :)